# How to resize (control) subscript sizes in MathJax

Tags: html, latex, mathjax

I have included the MathJax library in me HTML by including within the 'head' tag of my HTML.

```
<head>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
  </script>
</head>
```

Then, I used the delimiter to signal the MathJax parsing...

```
 \[\sigma_{X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
```

But note, the terrible sizing ratio between 'm' and its subscript 'X'.

[image]

**I simply want to control this sizing.** Or have MathJax configured to yield, what should be standard ratios between identifier and sub- or super-script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may control the size with LaTeX syntax (rather than MathJax configuration):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MathJax</title>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
\[\sigma_{\tiny X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
\[\sigma_{\scriptsize X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
\[\sigma_{\small X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
\[\sigma_{X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
\[\sigma_{\large X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
\[\sigma_{\Large X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
\[\sigma_{\LARGE X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
\[\sigma_{\huge X}^{2} = VAR[X = E[(X-m_X)^2]\]
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, only `footnotesize` does not work for me ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m14eorst/)).

Comment: So yous solution doesn't change the sub-script sizing. Basically there is no effect taken by the LaTex keywords. However, when i use the following `<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script >` version of MathJax, you code (and my code) is properly sized. But I think this an older version for MathJax that is no longer supported.

Comment: @sbaby171 Edited!! Thank you for pointing this out, I had taken my code from a (very) old answer of mine. This updated minimal code gives me a good result on IE, Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Please comment again if you need so we solve this one ;)

Comment: Your stuff worked. The issue was I had CSS font settings that were messing with the rendering. Basically, the math equations were placed within a div block that had font setting that were messing with the rendering...

Answer (score 2):

MathJax does use a smaller size for the super- and subscripts, but it is possible that your browser has a minimum font size specified and that this is preventing the size that MathJax requested from being used.  Can you check your browser's font settings to see if that is the case?

Also, MathJax has its own setting for the minimum font size that is to be used in super- and subscripts (8px).  If your page is typeset in a very small font, it may be that you are running into that.  If that is the case, you can override that via the following configuration:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script>
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    ready: function () {
      var math = MathJax._.core.MmlTree.MmlNodes.math.MmlMath;
      math.defaults.scriptminsize = '0px';
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

which sets the minimum to 0px, effectively removing it entirely.  Note that this does not override the browser settings, so if it is the minimum size set in the browser that is causing the problem, there is nothing MathJax can do about that.

Comment: So I tried your solution with no avail. It should be noted that I have tried setting the `mathsize` attributue of MathML `mn` and `mi` tags. The only solution i have been about to find was to use the following MathJax `<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script >`.

Comment: Your stuff worked. The issue was I had CSS font settings that were messing with the rendering. Basically, the math equations were placed within a div block that had font setting that were messing with the rendering...